# Can I install "JSON Viewer" extension for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: extension, visual-studio-2019

After I upgraded Visual Studio to version 2019, I cannot install the JSON View extension.

[image: VSIX Installer]

[image: log file]

> ```
> > 4/10/2019 9:51:09 AM - Skipping 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft
> > SDKs' as it doesn't exist 4/10/2019 9:51:09 AM - The extension with ID
> > 'c21a2a7b-7b1c-45c9-bee3-3bdc0715bdc9' is not installed to Microsoft
> > Visual Studio Community 2019. 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM - Extension cannot
> > be installed to the following products due to missing prerequisites:
> > 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM -  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> > 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM -
> >         ------------------------------------------------------- 4/10/2019
> > 9:51:10 AM -        Identifier   :
> > Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM -
> >         Name         : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor 4/10/2019
> > 9:51:10 AM -        Version      : [15.0,16.0) 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM -
> >         Error        : The prerequisite version specified does not match the
> > version installed 4/10/2019 9:51:10 AM -  4/10/2019 9:51:14 AM -
> > InstallProgressPage ChangeType: 'SingleTarget' operationCount: '2'
> > Text: 'Modifying Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019...' 4/10/2019
> > 9:51:14 AM - The following target products have been selected...
> > 4/10/2019 9:51:14 AM -  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> > 4/10/2019 9:51:14 AM -  4/10/2019 9:51:14 AM - Capping recursion at 5
> > directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
> ```

I also checked data in extension.vsixmanifest where I found:
[image: visxmanifest file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I upgraded Visual Studio to version 2019, I cannot install the JSON View extension.

The extension isn’t compatible with Visual Studio 2019 according to the manifest file. Of course the manifest file doesn’t actually appear to be for the extension your trying to install (the unique hash does not match). You will have to wait for the author to update it.

The marketplace download for this extension was automatically updated when Visual Studio 2019 was released to indicate it was compatible but looking at the code for the extension that isn’t possible due to the packages it uses.

*I also looked at the actual manifest file for the extension, and the prerequisites is also set for 15.0 instead of 16.0, without a recompile the extension can’t support VS2019.*